# Typescript Camera for a Mario game

Tags: javascript, canvas, typescript, html5-canvas, game-physics

I am trying to make a mario game for educational purpose (no phaserjs or any other engine).

What I basically want to do now is having some sort of camera that follows Mario.

At this moment Mario can walk one way and disappear from the screen. I'm looking for a way to implement some sort of camera that follows Mario.

I have a canvas looking like this

```
var w = 720, h = 480;

var canvas: HTMLCanvasElement;
var ctx: CanvasRenderingContext2D; 
var downForce = 2;
```

HTML

```
<canvas id="canvas" width="720" height="480" style="border:1px solid #c3c3c3;"></canvas>
```

My GameLoop is looking like this at the current moment.

```
    function gameLoop() {

    requestAnimationFrame(gameLoop);
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, w, h);
    ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(174,238,238)";
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, w, h);
    ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(14,253,1)";
    var floor = ctx.fillRect(0, h - 45, w, 45);
    mario.drawSprite();
    pipe.drawSprite();
    mario.addGravity();
}
```

I made a Camera.ts file

```
    class Camera {

    x: number;
    y: number;
    width: number;
    height: number;

    constructor(){}

    View(input: any):any {
        this.x = 0;
        this.y = 0;
        this.width = canvas.width;
        this.height = canvas.height;
    }
}
```

If I am correct, the camera should be moving with the running mario.
Looking like this

```
function keyboardInput(event: KeyboardEvent) {


switch (event.keyCode) {
    case 65: case 37: //a
        mario.setSpriteUrl("graphics/mario/small/Running-mario-left.gif");
        mario.numberOfFrames = 4;
        mario.position.x -= 10;

        Camera.View = Math.floor(mario.position.x + (mario.frameWidth/2) - (Camera.prototype.View.width / 2))
        break;
```

I am not sure if that is the correct calculation in order to 'move' the camera. But Visual Studio shows that the property view does not excist.

I am stuck with implimenting a camera feature. I would really appreciate it if somone could help me out. I suspect that I also should change the gameloop in order to get the camera 'working'

Answer (score 1):

The expression `Camera.prototype.View.width` doesn't make sense because `View` is a method of `Camera`. In other words, the following code compiles:

```
var c = new Camera();
c.View(null);
```

Given this mistake, it seems you are confused about classes and instances, and methods, you should learn about how classes work in TypeScript [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html). If you want `Camera.View`, you should learn about static properties from the article.

If you intended to create a default view of canvas width and height, you should do this:

```
var view = new Camera();
view.x = 0; view.y = 0;
view.width = canvas.width; view.height = canvas.height;
```

However, the code `Camera.View = Math.floor(...)` doesn't make sense at all because `Camera.View` isn't defined to be anything. You might have intended to set the x-position of the view. If that's the case, given the `view` variable, you can do:

```
view.x = Math.floor(mario.position.x + (mario.frameWidth/2) - (view.width / 2));
```